# Помогите выполнить задачу на Python

Tags: python

Напечатать таблицу умножения на число n (значение n вводится с клавиатуры; 1<=n<=9).

Решил так:

```
a=1
n+=1
for i in range(1, 9, 1):
    print(n*i)
```

не пашет. что сделано не так?

Comment: число вводится с клавиатуры. что такое n+=1? и в range крайнее правое значение не учитывается. должно быть range(1,10) (если шаг равен 1, его можно не указывать)

Comment: оператор присваивания, чтобы каждый последующий раз число умножалось на 1, 2, 3 и так далее

Comment: зачем вам оператор присваивания, если число вводится с клавиатуры? вам его уже дали. оно не должно меняться. меняется у вас число `i`. да и потом. даже в таком варианте, у вас ваш оператор присваивания (инкремент) находится вне цикла. то есть, бесполезен.

Answer (score 1):

Код:

```py
n = int(input('n = '))

for i in range(0, 10):
    print(f'{n}*{i} = {n * i}')
```

Где `n` - на какое число нужна таблица умножения.

Вывод:

```
n = 9
9*0 = 0
9*1 = 9
9*2 = 18
9*3 = 27
9*4 = 36
9*5 = 45
9*6 = 54
9*7 = 63
9*8 = 72
9*9 = 81
```